# userform always ontop after add new workbook excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I got one userform with a commandbutton on it, this button is use to create a new workbook. I want this userform on top of the new created workbook after click the button. Any idea?(For excel 2007, userform is always on top, **but not for excel 2016**)

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Workbooks.Add

End Sub
```

Comment: With your code it's already on top for me. Please, eleborate, is this a modal form or not? If it's modeless and your meaning of always is really ALWAYS, look over [here](http://allapi.mentalis.org/apilist/SetWindowPos.shtml).

Comment: sorry, forget to mention. I'm using Excel 2016. for example, I got the first workbook. After clicking the button, new workbook created but userform still sticks to the first workbook. The userform is modaless

Comment: unfortunately, I has not 2016, but I think that using API functions can solve your problem (first you get `hwnd` of your form with [`FindWindow`](http://allapi.mentalis.org/apilist/FindWindow.shtml) and after that place form as `TopMost` with [`SetWindowPos`](http://allapi.mentalis.org/apilist/SetWindowPos.shtml)). Unfortunately, I can't test it on 2016, as I mentioned before, so I think that I cant post it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try placing the following snippet on top of the userform's code module.

```
Option Explicit
Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal clsName As String, ByVal wndName As String) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetParent Lib "user32" (ByVal hChild As Long, ByVal hParent As Long) As Long

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Static h As Long
  If h <= 0 Then h = FindWindow("ThunderDFrame", Me.Caption)
  If h <= 0 Then Exit Sub
  Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = Workbooks.Add
  SetParent h, Application.Windows(wb.Name).hwnd
  wb.Activate
End Sub
```

This will make the new workbook the `Parent` of the user-form. It implies that the form will unload when you close the new workbook. If your goal is to keep the form alive for whatever workbook or worksheet is active, some other techniques can be used, maybe the easiest of which is by handling the `Workbook_SheetActivate` event.

Comment: it works for first time, second time the button's not working although it on top of new workbook. Unless you close the userform and reopen again.

Comment: @Amos try the modified version.

Comment: you can also, possibly, save the window number `h` as a data member of the form and calculate it once in `UserForm_Initialize()`. Then you use it whenever needed with windows API. You get the idea..